# Tile based layout with overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want to display a tile based map for a game. My current approach is to have a fixed sized div and to place absolute positioned smaller divs into that outer div. If there is something on the map at a given coordinate, I set the background picture for the div at that position. (see http://dungeonpilot.com)

Now I don't want the outer div to be fixed sized. I would like the inner div to use the whole browser space. I think I can achieve this by setting width and height to 100%. But in case, that I make the browser window small, so that some of the inner tiles aren't visible anymore, I would like to see scrollbars. But somehow, neither setting overflow to auto for the outer div, nor to the documents body does the trick.

Where and how do I have to set the overflow attribute, to get the intended behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution!
Apply

```
overflow: scroll;
```

to the #masters_view and #party_view divs.
Tell me if it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't works for me; neither in a Safari, nor in Firefox. But this is what I've initially tried. The url is just an example, both example dungeons have a fixed size div. The dungeon-view I now want to design is a one, where the size get's enlarged when more and more of the dungeon gets revealed. If the revealed dungeon exceeds the containing browser window, I would like to have "native" scroll bars.

Comment: Could you send a live preview? Maybe codepen.io? You could try min-width to the dungeon element, but I do not quite understand the used coding...

Comment: I've boiled it down to http://jsfiddle.net/VyQYx/ It seemed like the ´position:relative;´ in the outer div was the problem. I have really hard times, understanding this css mess ;-)

Comment: I'm using chrome and the biv scrolls both was... Maybe a browser bug or I don't understand the question, you want to let the .dungeon-canvas-full-screen div scroll don't you?

Comment: The example now works. But it differs from my first version (that didn't worked) because it had that "position: relative" line and that seemed to be the reason, why it didn't worked.